# .NET Core Identity How to set option value based on database

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I need to change parameter value for `IdentityOptions` dynamically from db. So, in my `ConsigureServices(...)` method in `Startup.cs`:

```
services.AddIdentity<AppUser, IdentityRole>(option =>
{
    option.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 3; // I need to set this value dynamically from database when server starts
}).AddEntityFrameworkStores<DataContext>()
  .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

I have tried to inject `IdentityOptions` in my `Configure(...)` method but with no success:

```
public void Configure(
    IApplicationBuilder app,
    DataContext dataContext,
    IdentityOptions identityOptions)
{
    var sysPolicy = dataContext.SysPolicy.FirstOrDefault();
    identityOptions.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = sysPolicy.DisablePwdLoginFail;
}
```

It throws an exception like this (it seems that I can't inject it on my Configure):

```
System.Exception: Could not resolve a service of type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityOptions' for the parameter 'identityOptions' of method 'Configure' on type 'App.Startup'.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try out this:

```
services.AddIdentity<AppUser, IdentityRole>(
                    options =>
                    {
                        var scopeFactory = services.BuildServiceProvider().GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>();

                        using var scope = scopeFactory.CreateScope();
                        var provider = scope.ServiceProvider;
                        using var dataContext = provider.GetRequiredService<DataContext>();
                        options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = dataContext.SysPolicy.FirstOrDefault();
                    })
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<DataContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

NOTE: Building a `service provider` is an antipattern and will result in creating an additional copy of singleton services. I would suggest reading the configs from `appsettings.json` for example, then you can implement it without building the `service provider`

Comment: Thank you. Yes, it shows a warning message `Calling 'BuildServiceProvider' from application code results in an additional copy of singleton services being created. Consider alternatives such as dependency injecting services as parameters to 'Configure'`. But I need to get the value dynamically at runtime whenever user change it on the database without restarting the server.

Comment: It will change dynamically. When you register an instance it is being registered lazy. Which means this code will be called for each scope. Test it, it should work

Comment: I've tested it and it seems not updating the option value when the db value was changed without restarting the server. So, it still stay with the old one.

Comment: I think I should update the option value on my `Controller` whenever the `SysPolicy` model values was updated. Can I inject the option to my `Controller` so I can re-assign its value with the new one?

Comment: @JustinusHermawan yes, you can inject IOptions<IdentityOptions> into whatever instance you need. But again, options,ideally, should be immutable

Comment: I just changed it to inject `IOptions<IdentityOptions>` into my `Configure(...)` method instead. It seems work like a charm and now I can get rid of the warning message because there's no calling `BuildServiceProvider` anymore in my ConfigureServices(...).

Comment: Have you tried implementing `IConfigureOptions<IdentityOptions>`? Seems its a more cleaner approach